# SVG на сайте некорректно отображает кириллицу

Tags: html, html5, svg, текст

При размещении на хостинге в HTML-файле блока, содержащего **SVG** **текст**

```
<svg> - Кирриллица ломается.
```

Как настроить отображение UTF-8?

Comment: Может, приведете пример кода?

Comment: Почитайте  [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверено работает, если всё верно для начала svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```